# knockout.js how to init tinymce?

Tags: knockout.js, tinymce

I am trying to integrate timyMCE into knockout, the idea is, when click on the link, then show the content as non-editable, then click on test to edit to open tinymce. And then create a button to save and switch edit model into view model. 
Here is the sample code and tinyMCE didn't work now...
Thanks for the help.

And usually how should we debug knockout?

```
Sample code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Princa/zADEK/3/
```

Comment: your fiddle is missing the jQuery lib - here it is added: http://jsfiddle.net/DW8bd/

Comment: @Thariama yeah, I found it out later and now it works. Thanks! But still have a question on it: http://jsfiddle.net/Princa/DW8bd/9/ .while I hide the tinymce, it didn't update the self.selectedET() , so the content doesn't bind to the observable...how should I do that?

Comment: i am sorry, i am not common with knockout.js - so i can't tell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You need these bindings that will bind tinymce with your knockout model.
https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---tinyMCE

2) Your HTML with your textareas and display areas.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click:function(){showEditor(true)}">Show Editor</a> | 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click:function(){showEditor(false)}">Hide Editor</a>
<br/>

<div data-bind="text: fieldOne, visible:!showEditor()"></div>

<div data-bind="css:{'nodisplay':!showEditor()}">
    <textarea class="tinymce" data-bind="tinymce: fieldOne"></textarea>
</div>

<hr/>

<h2>Debug</h2>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(viewModel)"></div>
```

3) Your JS

```
var viewModel = {
    fieldOne: ko.observable("one"),
    showEditor:ko.observable(false)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

You can check this jsfiddle out.
http://jsfiddle.net/billaraw/kwpRV/

Comment: thanks a lot! it does help me for the 1st step, http://jsfiddle.net/Princa/DW8bd/10/ I have this step now, the problem is how should I have the save button to call tinymce to save content to the observable like EmailTemplate().etContent?

Comment: I changed the way you binded the tinymce with a foreach:selectedET and then binding the property. Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/billaraw/fX4PN/

Comment: great thanks!it does what I wanted. So do you know why we can't bind selectedET? and need to use this foreach trick?

Comment: The selectedET is binded. However better to bind the property like that because knockout handles it when it is null as well and behaves normally. It can also work with the "with" instead of foreach http://jsfiddle.net/billaraw/fX4PN/2/

Comment: so if we bind selectedET to the div, then selectedET should have data to be able to show the div content. What if we want to create a new, which don't have any selectedET object, but allow user to create a blank record then insert a new record? I still want to use the same tinymce object, but just with blank content and everything? http://jsfiddle.net/Princa/fX4PN/3/ like this, it works only if I click any existing link first, so bind data to selectedET, but if we refresh page and then click create new, then editor won't show up.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Princa/fX4PN/5/  check this out, I create a new blank object and bind to selectedET while click on Create New, is that a good way to do that? But then I think I still need to have some validation saying content can't be null, that will probably be going to the save event and detect if value == null. right?